# Equivalent of Presto's transform() function in hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, presto

I can't seem to find an equivalent of Presto's [transform()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform) function in Hive.

TLDR:  how do you apply a function to each element of an array in hive ?

More precisely I have an array containing zero or more structs. Each struct has the same schema and contains several variables including one `is_done` which is a boolean. What I want to do is to assess if there is at least one struct with the variable is_done as True in the array.

In Presto, we would use `transform` to extract the booleans then `array_max` to see if at least one is true:

```
array_max(transform(a.array_task, x -> x.is_done))
```

Comment: I guess yes, `transform()` is not there in hive. But what exactly is the function that you are looking for? We can suggest an alternative or you may have to create a UDF.

Comment: That's my second sentence: it applies a function to all elements of an array

Comment: Yes i understand that. But i'm asking what should the function do? For eg., It should +1 to all element or concat some character to all element.

Comment: You're right @ArunPalanisamy I wasn't super clear, I edited my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hive has no such functionality. Without using additional UDFs you can do it by exploding array and checking struct element like this:

```
with your_table as (select array(named_struct('is_done',true),named_struct('is_done',false)) initial_array) 

select t.initial_array, max(a.s.is_done) as is_done 
  from your_table t
       lateral view outer explode(initial_array) a as s --s is a struct
  group by  t.initial_array    
  ;
```

Result:

```
initial_array                           is_done 

[{"is_done":true},{"is_done":false}]    true
```